# Extract string from the text using R

Tags: r, regex

The input below is the text file. The below is the data input

```
From: abc@xyz.com

To: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com

tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com

lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com

Subject: Introduction to R

B-CC: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com

tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com

lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com
```

Required Output:

I need all the mail id into one object from To And B-CC. Challenge is all the email ids are not in one line its in different line. Need to copy all the email ids into one object

```
To: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com, lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com

B-CC: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com, lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com
```

Comment: Can you provide a `dput`? Also please show how would your desired output will look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(stringr)
str1 <- paste(str_trim(lines), collapse=', ')
str_extract_all(str1, perl('(?=To: ).*(?=, Subject)'))[[1]]
#[1] "To: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com,
#lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com"
str_extract_all(str1, perl('(?=B-CC:).*'))[[1]]
#[1] "B-CC: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com, 
#lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com"
```

Or using `stringi`

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_extract_all_regex(str1, '(?=To: ).*(?=, Subject)')[[1]]
 #[1] "To: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com,
 # lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com"

 stri_extract_all_regex(str1, '(?=B-CC:).*')[[1]]
 #[1] "B-CC: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com, 
 #lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com"
```

#### data

```
 lines <- readLines(n=8)
 From: abc@xyz.com
 To: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com
 tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com
 lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com
 Subject: Introduction to R
 B-CC: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com
 tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com
 lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com
```

Comment: Thank you for help me with this code. One Question: What if in case we dont have subject after To.

Comment: @suhasnr My code was based on what you posted.  If there is no subject, then is it `B-CC` that follows `.com `

Answer (score 2):

Same as @akrun's but with little modifications.

```
> library(stringr)
> lines <- readLines(n=8)
From: abc@xyz.com
To: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com
tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com
lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com
Subject: Introduction to R
B-CC: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com
tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com
lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com
> str1 <- paste(str_trim(lines), collapse=', ')
> str_extract_all(str1, perl('(?=To:\\s+).*?(?=,\\s+\\w+:|$)'))[[1]]
[1] "To: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com, lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com"
> str_extract_all(str1, perl('(?=B-CC:\\s+).*?(?=,\\s+\\w+:|$)'))[[1]]
[1] "B-CC: qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com, lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Read in the lines and prefix each line not having a colon with a space.  The result will be in DCF format so we can just use `read.dcf` to read it in, replacing any newlines with comma and space. The resulting structure will have components  `From`, `To`, `Subject` and `B-CC`.

```
Lines <- readLines("myfile.txt")

hasColon <- grepl(":", Lines)
Lines[!hasColon] <- paste("", Lines[!hasColon])

email <- read.dcf(textConnection(Lines))[1, ]
email <- gsub("\n", ", ", email)
```

giving:

```
> email[['To']]
[1] "qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com, lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com"
> email[['B-CC']]
[1] "qwe@xyz.com, ewq@xyz.com, tuu@xyz.com, vbn@xyz.com, lkj@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat input | sed 's/: /\n/' | awk '/To/{flag=1;next}/Subject/{flag=0}flag' > to.txt
cat input | sed 's/: /\n/' | awk '/B-CC/{flag=1;next}/FINISH/{flag=0}flag' > bcc.txt
```

If I have understood your question properly this will work for you.